# How can I solve the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

How can I solve the following differential equation by power series near the point $z=1$ $$(z^2-2z+2)w''+2(z-1)w'=0$$
Then I have to find the radius of convergence of the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be noticed that the general solution of the equation is as follows.
\begin{align}
(x^2-2x+2)w''+2(x-1)w' &= 0 \\
\frac{d}{dx} [ (x^2 - 2x +2) y' ] &= 0
\end{align}
Integrate both sides to obtain
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \int \frac{c_{1} \, dx}{x^2 - 2x + 2} = c_{1} \tan^{-1}(1-x) + c_{2}.
\end{align}
It is now easy to see that the resulting value can be expanded as a power series about $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the dreaded power series. Set $w(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w_n (z-1)^n$. Then differentiate to obtain $w'$ and $w''$. Then multiply each by it's corresponding polynomial, sum it all together, and set to zero. Use induction to find a recurrence relationship between the coefficients of the power series. The radius of convergence will be half the length of the interval between the first point where it breaks down (i.e., $w_{n+1}(z-1)^{n+1} \geq w_n(z-1)^n$ for all $n>N$ for some $N$ for some set $z$, then $z_1$ and $z_2$, the breaking points, will be the infimum and supremum of the two such sets of $z$)  and the second point, which you can identify using the recurrence relation. What a sadistic professor, making you expand about $z=1$...